# JQuery Datepicker Validation not working for Multiple Dates with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, jquery-ui-datepicker

I didn't use jquery.ui's datepicker for one because I needed to select multiple dates, so I am using [Keith Wood's](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) datepicker in an EditorTemplate for my Date fields:

```
    @model Nullable<DateTime>
    @{
        string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
        string id = name.Replace(".", "_");
        string dt = Model.HasValue ? String.Format("{0:d}",(string)Model.Value.ToShortDateString()) : string.Empty;
    }        
    @Html.Hidden("", dt, new { @class = "datefield", @type = "date", @id = id, style = "display:none;" })
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#@id').datepick({
                renderer: $.datepick.themeRollerRenderer,
                multiSelect: 31,
                onSelect: function (dates) {
                    var value = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                        value += (i == 0 ? '' : ',') + $.datepick.formatDate(dates[i]);
                    }
                    $('#@name').val(value)
                    var form = $(this).parents().find('form')[0];
                    // form.validate(); // this causes error (Object doesn't support property or method 'validate') whats up with that?
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

And here is the definition of the DateTime field in my Data Class in which my ViewModel inherits:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
```

And here is the client side validation snip-it which is returning an invalid status:

```
    form.validate({ 
        rules:{
            StartDate: { 
                required: true
                ,dpDate: true 
            }
        },
        messages: {
            StartDate: 'Please choose at least one date'
        }
    });

    if (form.valid()) { // never reached }
```

So now I'm finalizing the last bit of validation for this inline datepicker. As you see I have a hidden field that is populated by the datepicker and it contains valid dates, but comma delimited and which does not translate to a datetime. It is valid when I choose just a single date. Is there a generic solution for validating the delimited data as a type?

I am basically looping a database call using the multiple dates but would still like to validate that the delimited data is of type DateTime.

Regards,

Brandon

Comment: Also note, removing the existing custom form.validate({ ... }) function does not change the results in any way, it seems its being overridden and not in effect.

Comment: Another note, I tried changing my Model to **public List<Nullable<DateTime>> StartDate { get; set; }** yielding the same result as before

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Plugins require a jQuery object.

If your form ID is **myForm** you would use the plugin like this:

`$('#myForm').validate({ ... });`

`$('#myForm').valid();`

Comment: this is clearly not the problem, I am able to validate just fine with a single date, the problem is when the hidden field has a value of "mm/dd/yyyy,mm/dd/yyyy" which is clearly not a valid date, I need the validation to parse on the comma delimited value. Just for kicks, I ensured the form was a jQuery object throughout, not relying on pure javascript, $("#trCreate form").validate({ ... }) yielding the same result.